# how to deploy laravel (using mysql) to railway.app

Tags: php, laravel, deployment, railway

- **deploy laravel in** **railway.app** ( using database mysql ) errors
- I use github repository *https://github.com/TanhGL/tanhpn_blog-railway.app*
- **Variable configuration**

  ```
  APP_NAME=Laravel
  APP_ENV=production
  APP_KEY=base64:cXdsNTZkbWduMjNyOHhiZmJyNzltc2JtaXUwejFud3Q=
  APP_DEBUG=true APP_URL=http://localhost
  DB_CONNECTION=mysql
  DB_HOST=containers-us-west-129.railway.app
  DB_PORT=6776 DB_DATABASE=railway
  DB_USERNAME=root
  DB_PASSWORD=******
  NIXPACKS_BUILD_CMD=composer install && php artisan key:generate && php artisan migrate && php artisan db:seed  && php artisan storage:link && php artisan passport:keys && php artisan optimize && php artisan config:clear && php artisan cache:clear && php artisan migrate --force && npm install bower && ./node_modules/bower/bin/bower install && npm run prod
  ```
- I tried many ways but all **railway.app** error [errors image on here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2zOu.png)

Comment: Did you deploy this successfully now?